# python gevent handling long blocking operations

Tags: python, flask, gevent

I am using gevent with flask and pymongo. I have an API endpoint where I will need to loop over a large number of results coming from pymongo to do some CPU calculation (speed mean, distances between geocordinates, ...).

I am wondering if gevent provides some functionnality to handle this kind of long blocking operation. It seems I can use `gevent.sleep` in my loop to trigger context switch between greenlets but it does not seem very clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gevent.sleep(0)` to yield to the hub (what you mean by context switch) is actually perfectly legitimate and the way to go. This is clean and the way mentionned in the doc [gevent doc](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html).